# テキストファイルへの書きだし python

Tags: python

初心者です。テキストファイルに書き出ししても、
反映されません。
ファイルがない場合は、カレントディレクトリにファイルが作られてと…教本にかいてますが、カレントディレクトリがどこにあるのかもよくわかりません。

Comment: 実際に実行したコードも示してもらわないと具体的な回答が出来ないと思います。後からでも [編集] 出来ますので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 質問の内容を整理すると2つあるように読み取れました。1つは "pythonでファイルを書き出すコードを書いたが、このコードで正しいですか？"、もう1つは "カレントディレクトリとは何でしょうか？"  です。そこで提案ですが、一旦後者についての質問として再編していただけると回答しやすい気がします。

Answer (score 1):

カレントディレクトリの場所は`os.getcwd()`で取得できます。

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

ここで指定されたフォルダに保存されます。
フォルダを変えるには、`os.chdir("フォルダのパス")`を使います。